# undefined index in php page

Tags: php, sql

I am getting error message :

> undefined index:

in my code. Below is the function on the line

`if($user['flagged'] == 1){
    $flag = "Your last payment has been flagged as NOT RECEIVED.";
}`
 it says  Undefined index: flagged

How can  this be fixed

Comment: if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg']=="success")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `isset()` to check it first

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg']==="success"){
    $log_prompt = '<span style="color:red">You Have successfully registered. Login Now!</span>';
}
```

if the first condition `isset($_GET['msg'])` returned false, it will escape the second part of the if condition and will not print your message.

read more about [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Answer (score 2):

Just check if msg index of global array $_GET is set. For example

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg']==="success")
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the page the URL must me something like this:

> localhost/your_page.php?msg=something_value

But your app mustn't return error when in URL there isn't `?msg=value`... You have to use `isset()`

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == "success")
```

> === is recommended

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] === "success")
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php